# What is the minimum web storage when creating a 500 user email accounts?

Tags: email-server, storage, web-hosting

I have a client that needs a website and an email server. Web hosting provider nowadays offers a package of domain registration, web hosting and email hosting.

Now, my client needs to create at least 500 email user accounts. It is a construction company which means the users will be sending/receiving graphical images using their emails which was created with the domain.

Now my question is, what is the minimum web storage of 500 email accounts? Is 20gb web storage will satisfy the 500 users?

Note that the email content is more on images.

Comment: Seriously, what about you sit down and estimate the amount of space for one account - which you can do a LOT better than us because you can ask the client questions. Then you multiply that by 500 for a start. We do not do performance questions here like this becasue basically you have all the info, we do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot determine space by the information you have given. Images can take pretty much space, so definitely the value you stated is insufficient.

You must consider:

- how e-mails are stored: on the server side or downloaded into the client most of the time
- what are the size/attachment limitations
- what is the average number of e-mails/day/account
- what is the average size of an e-mail
- what inbox size limit will you put in the users

So if you have 500 users with 200MB limit per inbox that will make a maximum of 100GB, but you must make sure that users will not exceed this. If some have many e-mails and you must increase their inbox you should take that into consideration.